# Get Netbeans to Auto-suggest Zend Framework components

Tags: zend-framework, netbeans-7

I've recently installed ZF, and haven't had any issues using it, however when I'm working in Netbeans, I'd like for it to recognize and suggest ZF components.  For example, when I type:

```
$config = new Zend_
```

I want it to auto-complete or suggest:

```
Zend_Registry
```

Or when I try to use:

```
Zend_Registry::getInstance();
```

I'd like for Netbeans to auto-suggest getInstance and recognize documentation for it.  I figure it has something to do with including the library inside the application, but I'm not sure where exactly to set this?  I have the library set for include_path inside php.ini, and the components work as expected in the browser, so no issues there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Netbeans menu go `Tools > Options > PHP` under `General` tab `Global Include Path` section click `Add Folder`. Add `Zend` folder from your library, confirm everything. Let Netbeans finish scanning and you're done.