# Doesn't work autocomplete in Netbeans for Zend Framework libraries

Tags: zend-framework, autocomplete, netbeans-7

I have to projects with the same structure, but various versions of ZF: 
old with ZF 1.11.4 and new with ZF 1.111.11.
Source folder contains^

```
31.05.2012  15:15             7 996 .zfproject.xml
25.06.2012  12:53    <DIR>          application
09.11.2012  13:01    <DIR>          cron
11.03.2012  15:11    <DIR>          library
09.11.2012  17:41    <DIR>          nbproject
09.11.2012  13:01    <DIR>          public
```

In library folder places Zend and My lib folders. In old project, when I code something autocomlite work perfect, in new - it doesn't work. Projects have some properties.

Netbeans version - 7.2, Windows 7.

This solution - [Get Netbeans to Auto-suggest Zend Framework components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10096728/get-netbeans-to-auto-suggest-zend-framework-components) doesn't work, because netbeans says, that library folders are already in my project

Answer (score 2):

you want to make sure you add the library to the global include path in Netbeans.

Accessed from the **Tools** drop down menu, then select **Options**, click the **PHP** icon and refer to the **General** Tab.

Netbeans will be the only consumer of this include path, it will not effect your PHP or Zend Framework setup at all. Primarily this information is used for autocomplete and hinting.

[image]

Not the project include path, accessed from the **Properties Menu** for each Project.

[image]

Unless you have a very specific and compelling reason, there is no real reason to have 2 versions of ZF 1.11. You may as well discard the ZF 1.11.4 and just use the ZF 1.11.11 or even upgrade to ZF 1.12, I doubt you will experience any difficulty with compatibility.

Typically when on a dev machine I just add the most current version of ZF 1 and ZF 2 to my PHP include path and to my Netbeans Global include path. This will make both libraries available wherever I need them without any more configuration.

Comment: But what about projects specific libraries?
I can't add it into global path, but cant sow them classes in autocomplition in new project. Old project correctly show its own libraries.

Comment: Man you got a mess, maybe you should try a reinstall. Anything available to the autoloader or the php include should be avialable to netbeans for autocomplete and hinting. Could also be your expectations are not inline with reality.

Comment: Netbeans reinstallation doesn't help, but when I recreate projects from mercurial repository and create new project with source clone - autocompliton starts work.